# C++: Use Derived-class-only variables from Base class

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, derived-class

Imagine that I have two similar structures A and B. Both A and B have a pointer to A, but A has an additional pointer to either A or B.

I thought of something like this with a Base and a Derived class

```
template <bool T> struct Derived;
struct Base { Derived<0> *p1; };
template <> struct Derived<0> : public Base { Base *p2; };
template <> struct Derived<1> : public Base {};
```

where A is `Derived<0>` and B is `Derived <1>`.

The problem here is that when accessing a class through `p2`, the compiler does not know which of the Derived classes it is, and something like this gives an error.

```
Derived<0> x, y, z;
x.p2 = &y;
y.p2 = &z;
x.p2->p2; // Error
```

Do any of you know any magical workaround, preferably using only compile-time features?

I also need to know which type of Derived am I using, so that I know if I can use p2 or not.

If it helps, you can visualise things as a double-linked list, where `Derived<0>` is a normal node, `Derived<1>` is the end node, `p1` is the *prev* pointer and `p2` is the *next* pointer.

**Edit**: It does not need to use a Base-and-Derived-class-type structure, it can be anything.

Comment: It's an error because `x.p2` is a pointer to `Base`, which does not have a `p2` member and so the `->p2` fails to resolve to anything. You can `dynamic_cast<Derived<0>>(x.p2)` and check if the result is not `nullptr`.  If it's not then you can access `->p2` through the casted pointer.

Comment: (Note that the base class must be polymorphic for `dynamic_cast` to conditionally cast correctly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is based on double dispatching, the same idea that is behind the most known visitor pattern.

It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<iostream>

template<int>
struct Derived;

struct Visitor {
    template<int N>
    void visit(Derived<N> &);
};

struct Base {
    Derived<0> *p1;
    virtual void accept(Visitor &) = 0;
};

template<>
struct Derived<0>: public Base {
    void accept(Visitor &) override;
    Base *p2;
};

template<>
struct Derived<1>: public Base {
    void accept(Visitor &) override;
};

template<>
void Visitor::visit(Derived<0> &d) {
    std::cout << "Derived<0>" << std::endl;
    d.p2->accept(*this);
}

template<>
void Visitor::visit(Derived<1> &) {
    std::cout << "Derived<1>" << std::endl;
}

void Derived<0>::accept(Visitor &v) {
    v.visit(*this);
}

void Derived<1>::accept(Visitor &v) {
    v.visit(*this);
}

int main() {
    Visitor v;
    Derived<0> x, y;
    Derived<1> z;
    x.p2 = &y;
    y.p2 = &z;
    x.p2->accept(v);
}
```

See it up and running on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cPU55EsVsAHNbcg7).

If you can use C++17 and thus `std::variant`, things are far more simple:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<variant>

template<int>
struct Derived;

struct Base {
    Derived<0> *p1;
};

template<>
struct Derived<0>: public Base {
    std::variant<Derived<0> *, Derived<1> *> p2;
};

template<>
struct Derived<1>: public Base {};

struct Visitor {
    void operator()(Derived<0> *d) {
        std::cout << "Derived<0>" <<std::endl;
        std::visit(*this, d->p2);
    }

    void operator()(Derived<1> *) {
        std::cout << "Derived<1>" <<std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Visitor v;
    Derived<0> x, y;
    Derived<1> z;
    x.p2 = &y;
    y.p2 = &z;
    std::visit(v, x.p2);
}
```

See it up and running on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qFTHg8TjWAABmSa3).